# Vector Spaces - Understanding counter exmaple

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am trying to understand a counter-example to say that this statement is false:

Let $U,W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$, than  $U ∪W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Counter Example:

Let $V= \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $U=span \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right \}$ and let $W=span \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right \}$

So $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \notin U ∪ W$ .

I do not understan why is  $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \notin U ∪ W$?

Or first should I ask, what is $U ∪ W$ equal in this case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Were $(1,1)$ to be in the union it would have to be in either $U$ or $V$, but it is in neither.

Comment: $U=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\y\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and $V=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$, where $x,y \in\Bbb{R}$. Thus the "union" of these two subspaces is the set of vectors which either look like $(0,y)$ or $(x,0)$. Now you can check!

Comment: Ohh Ok, I thought that the union makes it look like $(x,y)$, Thank you!

Comment: Read up on the vector space "sum". That makes it look like $(x, y)$.

Comment: @TomCollinge Thank you I will search it!

Answer (score 2):

$$ U\cup V = \{a\cdot (0\;1), a\in\mathbb{R}\} \cup\{a\cdot (1\;0), a\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
So there are no vectors with both coordinates different than zero

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: you welcome, I always find this confusing..